# Public swift class inside objective c framework

Tags: swift, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods

I am building an objective c framework and I have a public header file which I can see it in headers folder, inside the .framework folder, when I build the framework. I am trying to create a public swift class which also would be visible outside of the framework. It is used as a pod and I use its compiled version, and I want the swift class to be visible from the swift app that uses the pod. Any thoughts?

Comment: so you created a public swift class, added it to framework... what's your problem?

Comment: When I compile the framework and download it as a pod from git, I can not access its public methods, thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: Still not enough information to be helpful in any way. I recommend following a tutorial (e.g. this one: https://medium.com/@cecilia.humlelu/creating-a-hybrid-framework-ebe2dba4e431) and posting a question if you are stuck on a particular stage.